# How could I find ubuntu's IP installed on vmware, without connecting to it?

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, vmware-player

I was running an ubuntu 14.04 on a VMware, I changed some of system's files on it, so there is no UI and I can't access to the command line when I run it.
However I was able to connect to it through ssh.

After I upgraded my VMware, all IPs associated to all OS running on this VMware changed, so I don't know the IP of the ubuntu, which I need for accessing to it through ssh.
So far I tested

> ipconfig

on cmd, but it just show first three part of IP :
192.168.138.1
I need somehow to find the fourth part.

Is there any way to find out the IP for an vm from vm workstation, or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could access your router interface and just check the connected IP addresses. Your virtual machine should be listed there.

If thats not a possibility you can use external Software like nmap (note: only use this in your private network, because its use is controversial in public network) to scan your IP-subnet. It should return all connected devices and open ports (e.g. ssh).

Comment: Thank you, router interface didn't work, but nmap woked just fine